# Inno Setup: Hide/Disable Component at runtime

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to disable or hide one of the component choices at run-time. I have created a custom wizard page with two radio buttons. If the first radio button is selected, I would like one of the components (CustomInstall) to not appear, or at least be disabled.

Of course, the custom page appears prior to the Components page.

I have tried to do this with a Check: parameter, but it appears that the [Components] section is evaluated at startup, and not when the page is displayed.

So my next thought was to add some code to my CurPageChanged() so that I could remove or disable the item from the CheckListBox (which I think is called ComopnentsList), but I can't find any documentation on TNewCheckListBox.

Does anyone know more about this class? Will what I am thinking work?

Comment: For further info: InnoSetup classes documentation is at http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
if CurPageID=wpSelectComponents then
begin
  if ExtraOptionAvailable() then
  begin
    Wizardform.ComponentsList.Checked[6] := true;
    Wizardform.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[6] := true;
  end else begin
    Wizardform.ComponentsList.Checked[6] := false;
    Wizardform.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[6] := false;
  end;
end;
```

Searching the Inno Setup newsgroups at http://www.jrsoftware.org/newsgroups.php was very helpful.

Comment: You added that in your `CurPageChanged()` function?

Comment: Yes, that's where it went.