# Inno Setup: Disable specific Types from menu - similar to Components method previously posted

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

**First I:**
Searched a lot but did not find anything that seemed to cover this, but i might be missing it. (my coding sucks so I don't always know the right thing to search)

**Scenario:**
I like using the drop down list approach of selection more than the radio buttons or check boxes. So I typically add a Type for each component and disable component screen so the user just selects the appropriate option.

However I would like sometimes to check if a condition is met before offering the ability to select or reduce the list altogether.

**What I did find:**
For conditions I found this post [Hide/Disable Component at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353990/inno-setup-hide-disable-component-at-runtime/7364460#7364460) I tried it his way works but I would like to do the same thing but with Types.

**Next?:**
I cannot find if there is something like `WizardForm.TypesList.ItemEnabled` (I know that is not a real call)

Can this be done without building a fully custom types page? Also can it be a true hide? (disable works for me as well, hide is just cleaner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **hide** a setup type conditionally, use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) in the `Types` section.

```pascal
[Types]
Name: "typeA"; Description: "A installation"
Name: "typeB"; Description: "B installation"
Name: "typeConditional"; Description: "Some other installation"; Check: CanInstallOther

[Code]

function CanInstallOther: Boolean;
begin
  Result := ...;
end;
```

---

I do not think you can really **disable** an item of the drop down list. You can prevent a user from selecting it, but you cannot make it gray or something.

Comment: This is better I prefer they not even see the option if the condition is met. Tested with FileExists, works as required. Thanks!